# returning a list

Tags: python, file, list, nested

i have a question regarding returning the following function
i am given a file with a food list that looks something like this:

```
'''
bread
bun

milk
soya milk
'''
```

and i have to return a list of lists of the foods eg, `[['bread','bun'], ['milk','soya milk']]`

i am very new to python and programming, therefore i am stuck on the for loop in order to create my lists.  any input would be greatly appreciated - kev

Comment: How are you grouping these foods?

Comment: they are grouped in the file by white space between lines, if there is a blank white space between sets of foods, that means the upper set is its own set

Answer (score 2):

that works...

```
grocery_list_file = open('foods.txt','r').read()
foods = grocery_list_file.split("\n\n") #split on blank lines

result = []
for food in foods:
   newFood = food.split("\n") # split the lines, creating the output...
   result += [newFood]
return result
```

in a single line:

```
print [f.strip().split("\n") for f in open('foods.txt','r').read().split("\n\n")]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty close. Instead of using `while len(next_food) > 0:`, you should use if and handle both case when next_food is blank and non blank. And like you comment indicates, right before return you should include the last sublist.

Another things to look check is whether next_food includes a newline at the end or not. You should strip the line break if it is there. Finally there is a shortcut alternative to the checking of `if len(next_food):`. Simply write `if next_food:` will do.

Answer (score 0):

You want to append the sublist when you reach the new category and then start a new sub_list. It is important to append the remaining sub_list to the end when you reach the end of the file.

```
new_list.append("\n")   #to make sure it appends the last category
for next_food in new_list:
        if next_food = "\n":
            result.append(sub_list)
            sub_list = []
        else:
            sub_list.append(next_food)
```

Comment: This won't work actually as it will skip the last category group. Check it! ;)

Comment: Good call. I'm not sure if sub_list will be local to the for loop. I don't think it will since it is declared outside.

Answer (score 0):

this is not a very good solution ... but its some fun tricks ..

```
>>> s = '''
... bread
... bun
...
... milk
... soya milk
... '''
>>> import re
>>> parts = re.sub("[\[\]']","",str(s.strip().splitlines())).split(", ,")
>>> import string
>>> print [map(string.strip,p.split(",")) for p in parts]
[['bread', 'bun'], ['milk', 'soya milk']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby


def build_grocery_list():
    # using "with" to open the file - recommended way
    with open("foods.txt") as f:
        # lines will contain all the lines in the file, without "\n" characters
        lines = f.read().splitlines()

        # initialize result as an empty list
        result = []

        # Now for the fun part: group file lines basing on whether they are empty
        # (bool(string) is analogous to as using "if string:" -- will be True if
        #  the string is not empty)
        #
        # groupby works in such a way that it appends stuff to the group as long
        # as "key" condition is the same, returning (key, group) pairs.
        #
        # So, we get pairs: (bool(string), string-group) where:
        # - bool(string) is the group "key", delimiting empty and non-empty
        #   strings
        # - string-group is a lazy *generator*, hence the "list(group)"
        for nonblank, group in groupby(lines, bool):
            if nonblank:
                result.append(list(group))

    return result
```

If you are learning Python, I really recommend that you familiarize yourself with the excellent [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module -- it's very handy!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and fairly readable way is:

```
>>> [el.strip().split('\n') for el in text.split('\n\n')]
[['bread', 'bun'], ['milk', 'soya milk']]
```

1. Splitting by `\n\n` leads to a line, immediately followed by a blank line
2. The `.strip()` removes the leading and trailing newlines, so only newlines between 
   elements are there
3. The `split` then breaks those elements are into a list, resulting in your list of lists

Alternatively, you could use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> [groups for groups in (list(g) for k, g in groupby(text.splitlines(), bool)) if groups[0]]
[['bread', 'bun'], ['milk', 'soya milk']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input file is small enough to be read entirely into memory, I'd do it like this:

```
with open('grocery_list.txt', 'rt') as grocery_list_file:
    data = grocery_list_file.read()

sublist = [item.strip().split('\n') for item in data.split('\n\n')]
```

Output:

```
sublist: [['bread', 'bun'], ['milk', 'soya milk']]
```